# Going through passport control in the UK coming from a non-EU country; will I be able to manage a short connection time?

Tags: uk, transit, lhr, short-connections

Sorry for the long title but I will be taking a red-eye flight and coming from Nairobi to London and then onwards to New York.

The connection time is only 1hr and 5 minutes. I am an EU citizen  but from what I've heard, the airport can reach its peak traffic during noon and the fact that I will probably have to go through passport control seeing as I'm coming from outside the EU makes me a bit nervous that I might miss my flight. I did read that there are new e-gates that make the process much faster so I won't have to queue but I'm not sure about that.

Is it worth changing my ticket or just leaving it?

Comment: You don't need to go through passport control unless you want to enter the UK. Whether you are coming from the EU or not makes no difference. Simply follow the purple signs for "Flight Connections".

Answer (score 8):

You won't have to go through passport control since you are not entering the UK (assuming you have booked this as a single ticket), but will have to go through security screening.

You can use the [Heathrow Connections tool](http://www.heathrow.com/flight-connections) to see exactly what you'll have to do and how long the airport wants you to allow. Just enter the flight numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If it's in a single booking, you usually have little to lose by booking that trip, because if you miss the connection, you'll be put on the next flight for free. You also don't clear immigration, but will clear security

If it's on separate tickets, you will need to clear immigration there's no way 1 hour will be enough.

Comment: "Absolutely nothing" is pushing it, unless your time is worth absolutely nothing. It can be rational in some situations to book a longer connection, if the delay you risk by being rebooked on the "next flight" would be unacceptably large.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Don't you always get put on the next flight, in other words the one you would've got by default if booking the second shortest connection?

Comment: Only if there is room on the next flight. And the alternative connection might be the same second leg but an earlier first leg -- or with a different airline altogether.